# Python setuptools: Distribute configuration files to OS specific directories

Tags: python, setuptools, setup.py

I am having kind of a chicken or the egg problem with Python setuptools.

What I am trying to achieve, is to distribute a configuration file with my pip package (which in itself is perfectly possible with `data_files` parameter in `setup.py`) to OS specific common locations for user configuration files (e.g. `~/.config` on Linux).

I figured out that OS "specificity" can be solved using `appdirs`[1] PyPi package. And there is my problem - the `appdirs` is not guaranteed to be installed when installing my own package since it is a dependency of my package and thus installed after it (promised chicken or the egg :) )

My `setup.py` contains something like this:

```
from setuptools import setup
from appdirs import AppDirs
...
setup(
...
    data_files=[
        (AppDirs(name, author).user_config_dir, ['config/myconfig'])
    ],
...
)
```

Can this be solved without writing my own version of setuptools (allusion intended ;) )?

[1]: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/appdirs

Comment: Not exactly answering your question but my advice would be to distribute a *generic* copy of your file with `data_files`, then at first run of your app, check with `appdirs` if the user specific file exists and if not create it at first run by copying the distributed files (which you can find using using `pkg_resources`).

Comment: @shevron That is actually much better solution than my original idea! :) Unfortunately, I am struggling with the `pkg_resources`.  Would you please make an answer (preferably with short snippet how about ding it) so I can tag it as correct? ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As I mentioned in my comment I would recommend distributing a generic copy of your file with your package and then copying it to the user's config dir at runtime if it does not exist.

This shouldn't be very hard and involves:

1. Using `setuptools`'s `package_data` (instead of `data_files`). This places the file where it is accessible at runtime using `pkg_resources`, in the "correct" location for the specific OS
2. When the program runs, use `appdirs` to look for a user-specific, locally installed file.
3. If it does not exist, use `pkg_resources` to find the file and copy it to the location provided by `appdirs`

While I haven't done this, this process should work nicely for multiple OSes and environments and as a bonus, during development too due to how `pkg_resources` works.

#### Example `setup.py`

In setup.py, you should make sure to include your data file for your package using `package_data`:

```
setup(
    # ...
    data_files={
        "my_package": [ "my_package.conf.dist" 
    }
    # ...
)
```

#### Example app code:

```
import os.path
import pkg_resources
import appdirs

def main():
    """Your app's main function"""
    config = get_config()
    # ... 
    # ...

def get_config():
    """Read configuration file and return its contents
    """
    cfg_dir = appdirs.user_config_dir('MyApplication')
    cfg_file = os.path.join(cfg_dir, 'my_application.conf')
    if not os.path.isfile(cfg_file):
        create_user_config(cfg_file)
    with open(cfg_file) as f:
        data = f.read()
        # ... probably parse the file contents here ...
        return data

def create_user_config(cfg_file):
    """Create the user's config file

    Note: you can replace the copying of file contents using shutil.copyfile
    """
    source = pkg_resources.resource_stream(__name__, 'my_package.conf.dist')
    with open(cfg_file, 'w') as dest:
        dest.writelines(source)
```

I hope this clears up the usage of `pkg_resources` and `package_data`.